# In BigQuery, why can I still query the geo_census_blockgroups table but cannot find it in the public data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I can run this query fine:

```
    a.geo_id,
    a.total_pop,
    a.white_pop,
    a.black_pop,
    a.hispanic_pop,
    a.asian_pop,
    a.amerindian_pop,
    a.other_race_pop,
    a.two_or_more_races_pop,
    b.blockgroup_geom
FROM `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_acs.blockgroup_2010_5yr` a 
join `bigquery-public-data.geo_census_blockgroups.us_blockgroups_national` b
using(geo_id)
limit 100
```

But when I search for the table `geo_census_blockgroups`, I can't find it.

[image: geo_census_blockgroups]

If I search boundaries, I cannot see block groups or census tracts.

[image: bigquery search]

Is `geo_census_blockgroups` being phased out or why doesn't it appear more easily in public data searches?

Comment: just as fyi: i don't have this problem - looked from Console and other means - see those datasets and tables - both `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_acs.blockgroup_2010_5yr` and `bigquery-public-data.geo_census_blockgroups.us_blockgroups_national` - and all rest of objects in those datasets

Comment: so, btw, `boundaries` looks like wrong word to search for something that does not have that word in it :o)

Comment: Searching `geo_census` doesn't yield anything for me. Any ideas why I can't see these public tables?

Comment: try simple  - `census` :o)

Comment: same problem, I don't see the geometries tables anywhere

Comment: I can see the dataset `geo_census_blockgroups` if I manually scroll through the available public data sets. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLwn1.png) . But I can confirm that I cannot search for it using the search bar provided using census, boundaries, geo or groups.  I created a public issue tracker for this https://issuetracker.google.com/200752146. Feel free to add more details on the tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Bigquery interface which you are using is in [Preview](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages)

You can use the  workaround of using the Legacy BQ interface to search for geo_census_blockgroups dataset in bigquery-public-data  by following the below steps.

1. Go to BigQuery UI.
2. Select **Disable Editor tabs**
3. Opt out Bugs and BigQuery UI will be switched to the Legacy BigQuery Interface.
4. Search for the dataset in the search bar using keywords and the searched dataset will appear.

[image]

[image]

Also for reference you can check the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/200752146), any update related to this will be provided there.